# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: java, maven, build, microservices, javabuilders

I am trying to build a proof of concept for microservices in java (eclipse) using maven Spring libraries and following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBkD-OBeL0s) tutorial.

Below is my POM file, which shows an error, that I could not resolve:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tutorials</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

</project>
```

On the tag `<parent>` I have the following error:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.tutorials:HelloWorld:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:
 1.2.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
 elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.2.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to 
 find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks.

**Edit:** In the directory User/.m2 I created a settings.xml file to overcome the proxy issue, as the following:

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Now the error is as the following:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.tutorials:HelloWorld:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:
 2.2.2.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has 
 elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.example.com and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

Comment: Are you behind a coporate proxy?

Comment: Exactly. I am behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: Checkout this article: https://medium.com/@petehouston/execute-maven-behind-a-corporate-proxy-network-5e08d075f744 I hope it helps

Comment: Really a project with Spring Boot 1.X ? It's End of Life since August 2019 https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019

Comment: @khmarbaise Okay now it is <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I followed the article, now the security part of the error is gone but I am left with this error: Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.tutorials:HelloWorld:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:
 2.2.2.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, ..... Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://...): proxy.example.com and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Comment: Behind a firewall/proxy configuration is not ok I suppose ...

Comment: Try mvn clean install -U

Comment: Can you access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in your browser ? Can you "curl https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" from your console ? Can you go in your browser to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.2.RELEASE/ ?

Comment: I can access these links with my browser but eclipse seems to be blocked from doing that, it is obviously due to security reasons in my place.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, Traveling Salesman, one of you should post the proxy part as a solution. This has helped me.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is of the certificate is not installed in your java security. As you had mentioned you were able to access the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
you need to export the certificate from the site information if you were using chrome.

After that, you need to install the certificate in the Keystore,
in the case of

**java 8 : jdk->jre->lib->security**

**java 11 : jdk->lib->security**

command to install the certificate :

**keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias  -file  -keystore  -storepass**

The question had been asked more than 2 years ago but hope someone will get help from this.