Intellji showing the sun.security.provider.certpath error
trying to configure the spring boot in intellji - Mac, when I try to add the dependencies using maven getting the following error. Can you anyone guide me how to solve this> tried all the possibilities but still facing the same.
Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springdemo:demo2:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.5 (absent): org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.5 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>
        <groupId>org.springdemo</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo2</name>
        <description>demo2</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>21</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/KnUX23lG.png


so, it can't find a dependency you've added in your pom. How about using one that can be found?

@Stultuske updated, pls check once

did the error change?

no same, screenshot updated

why do you try to set it as a parent?

its default project files, i didn't change anything. just download the setup from SpringInitializr and trying to run it in intellji

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I faced similar issue in part and it's related to Java certificate. Have you recently upgrade the Java version? Hopefully this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598487/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-and-parent-relative

@vik on which location we need to install the keytool certificate?

For Java 21, you'll find cacerts in this directory 21.0.1-oracle/lib/security

still same error
